# Wordpress Website super slow to load (TTFB 8 seconds)

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

My WordPress website is loading super slowly and I don't understand why. I've been running a webpagetest but I don't understand it at all.

Here are the results : http://www.webpagetest.org/result/150319_2Q_15TC/

The TTFB seems to be the problem here. I checked using direct access on the website and not via DNS and it's exactly the same.

I'll be glad if someone could give me a hand on this one !

Comment: Its hosted on a cloud virtual private server. Other website are running fine on this server

Comment: (This question as it stands is highly localised to your situation, and as such is likely to be placed on hold. If you can generalise it a bit so that the particulars of the problem are added into the question, and so that the link is removed, that might help. Questions on Stack Overflow should ideally be written to benefit a wide audience, and if something will only ever apply to one person, it probably isn't a good fit).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is highly localised to one poster.

Comment: I'lld be have words with the host

Comment: @halfer TTFB = Time To First Byte. Regarding off-topic I don't agree. First of all, long TTFB means it takes a lot of time to serve the request on the server side. If another sites on the same server are running fine, then it is caused by the WP and/or plugins, their combinations etc. This can be an issue which is rare but not localized. Someone in future may benefit from this.

Comment: @Ghtay install the Query Monitor plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) and investigate what actually takes so long to execute.

Comment: @Paspas2.com Ok thanks, i'll try today and give you a feedback

Comment: @Dagon the host seems fist on other website so ... Might be a plugin or something. I'm using a theme with the 'livecomposer' plugin , i'll try to disable it

Answer (score 0):

So a bit late here.
I uninstalled everything a redo a full install. Now its working great.
I tried to reinstall a SEO plugin then the ttfb was super high again.
I think its might the thing !